# Rails ActiveRecord Update column values from iteration operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am decrypting encrypted values from column_name getting below output.

Now I want to update db column_name with the decrypted values from my script's output. How do I do that?

```
a=Model.pluck("column_name")

a.map { |i| Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64(i), :key=>'bh2hbhbd43hbh3bh3b') }
```

outputs:

```
 => ["49218123213167647472155545665651212", "46545649432177019560", "47511231231400014564554502209", "465944112312321312499558809", "4659445641231231231221669061537", "465914523564643217745645019560"]
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @xlembouras updated question. i just want to update all current values of column_name with new values from this output. I tried using #update_all and update_attributes but no success

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ask how to update this column with decrypted value? If yes, just iterate on all rows:

```
Model.all.each do |row|
  decrypted = Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64(row.column_name), :key=>'bh2hbhbd43hbh3bh3b')
  row.column_name = decrypted
  row.save!
end
```